Can the IOMMU (SMMUv3) be configured to partially use bypass mode and partially use translation mode?
I want to configure the following mappings:

Physical address 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF: Bypass mode
Physical address 0x100000000 to 0x1FFFFFFFF: Translation mode

I can use the following translation mode configuration:
iommu_map(pci_priv->iommu_domain,
  roundup(0x100000000, PAGE_SIZE),
  rounddown(0x100000000, PAGE_SIZE),
  roundup(0xFFFFFFFF + 0x100000000 - rounddown(0x100000000, PAGE_SIZE), PAGE_SIZE),
  IOMMU_READ | IOMMU_WRITE | IOMMU_CACHE);

However, how can I correctly configure the 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF range to use bypass mode effectively?
I would like to know how to configure the IOMMU to use partial bypass and partial translation mode.

Bypass can be configured per STE. See SMMU software guide.
